# Linq dinâmico com C#

Tags: c#, linq

Dentro do new no linq. eu preciso criar as propriedades dinâmicas baseadas em um data table como posso fazer isso?

```
var query = (from indicador in tableIndicado.AsEnumerable()
    group indicador by indicador.Field<string>("IND_CODUSU") into g
    select new {

      #region Privot Table mensal

      // Janeiro
      Jan_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 1).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Jan_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 1).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Jan_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 1).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Fevereiro
      Fev_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 2).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Fev_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 2).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Fev_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 2).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Março
      Mar_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 3).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Mar_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 3).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Mar_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 3).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Abril
      Abr_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 4).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Abr_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 4).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Abr_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 4).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Maio
      Mai_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 5).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Mai_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 5).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Mai_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 5).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Junho
      Jun_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 6).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Jun_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 6).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Jun_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 6).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Julho
      Jul_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 7).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Jul_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 7).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Jul_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 7).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Agosto
      Ago_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 8).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Ago_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 8).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Ago_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 8).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Setembro
      Set_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 9).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Set_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 9).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Set_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 9).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Outubro
      Out_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 10).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Out_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 10).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Out_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 10).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Novembro
      Nov_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 11).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Nov_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 11).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Nov_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 11).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      // Dezembro
      Dez_Valor = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 12).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL")),
      Dez_Meta1 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 12).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1")),
      Dez_Meta2 = g.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month == 12).Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")),

      #endregion
  });

return dataset;
```

Comment: Você quer criar as propriedades da consulta com base no nome da coluna (do dataset), isso?

Comment: Isso. Tenho que cria-las dinamicamente conforme vem do meu datatable

Comment: Não creio que seja possível, o ideal seria você utilizar uma estrutura de dados que não tivesse um tamanho fixo, assim você adicionaria os itens nela de maneira dinâmica, poderia ser uma List ou um Dictionary por exemplo.

Comment: Você pode me dar um exemplo de como adicionar com  List ou Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar eu começava por expressar melhor a intenção do meu código, fazendo um agrupamento das somas por mês:

```
var query = g.GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("MTA_DTINIANO").Month, 
   group => group, 
   (month, group) => new {
       Valor = group.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_INDVAL"),
       Meta1 = group.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META1"),
       Meta2 = group.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("MTA_META2")   
   }
);
```

E em vez de ter 36 campos metia o resultado da query num dicionário que podia indexar por mês

```
query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: Eu entendi o que você fez só que o problema é que as colunas do data table são montadas dinamicamente então eu posso ter colunas diferentes na hora de montar o group

Comment: @AlUnserAlbuquerque Acho que vai ter que dar um exemplo. O que posso acrescentar é que eventualmente pode fazer sentido acrescentar uma coluna que esta sempre presente de forma a poder fazer o agrupamento pelo seu valor.